# Why do I have to perform polynomial division when trying to find slant asymptotes

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, rational-functions

When trying to find the slant asymptote of $\frac{2x^2+x}{x-3}$, the way I thought was correct is to divide everything by $x$ to get $\frac{2x+1}{1-\frac{3}x}$. All that was left was to say that as $x$ tends to $\infty$, $\frac{3}x$ tends to $0$, so the asymptote is $2x+1$. Spoiler: it was not.
If I would do it the polynomial division way, I would get that the asymptote is $2x+7$. My question is: what is wrong with my way?

Helpful link though it did not answer my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526312/why-must-you-do-polynomial-long-division-to-find-oblique-asymptotes-of-rational)

Comment: I think you are mixing up limits with asymptotic behaviour. You did not prove $f(x)=\frac{2x^2+x}{x-3}\to 2x+1$ when $x\to\infty$ (i.e. better written: $f(x)-(2x+1)\to 0$ when $x\to\infty$): you have proven that $f(x)\sim 2x+1$ when $x\to\infty$ which is weaker. (After all, $2x+7\sim 2x+1$ itself!)

Comment: Exactly what is the definition of "slant asymptote"? (Say $f$ is our function and $y=L(x)$ is the line; if the definition is $f(x)/L(x)\to1$ fine, but if the definition is $f(x)-L(x)\to0$ then you simply haven't shown that.)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1959652/incorrect-method-to-find-a-tilted-asymptote?rq=1) might provide some insight.

Comment: The distinction that @StinkingBishop is talking about is related to a confusing mismatch of terminology. We say that two functions $f$ and $g$ are *asymptotic* (at infinity) if $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)/g(x))=1$. But we say that the non-vertical line $y=g(x)=mx+b$ is an *asymptote* (on the right) of the curve $y=f(x)$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=0$. (These both also have versions where $x\to-\infty$, of course.) And annoyingly, these are not the same!

Comment: PS: I once asked a [question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135093/terminology-for-sequences-functions-that-approach-each-other) asking for the *proper* term for functions $f$ and $g$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=0$, and nobody knew one. (The best advice seemed to be to just say ‘asymptotic’ with an ad-hoc adverb or a warning that the term is being used in a nonstandard sense.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asserting that $2x+1$ is an asymptote means that$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2+x}{x-3}-(2x+1)=0.$$But$$\frac{2x^2+x}{x-3}-(2x+1)=\frac{6x+3}{x-3}$$and therefore$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2+x}{x-3}-(2x+1)=6\ne0.$$On the other hand\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2+x}{x-3}-(ax+b)=0&\iff\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-a x^2+2 x^2+3 a x-b x+x+3 b}{x-3}=0\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}-a+2=0\\3a-b+1=0\end{array}\right.\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}a=2\\b=7.\end{array}\right.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

$(2x+1)(1-3/x)^{-1};$

Now for large $x$ expand the second factor:

$(2x+1)\cdot$

$(1 +(-1)(-3/x)+O(1/x^2))=$

$2x+1+(6x)/x+O(1/x)=$

$2x+7+O(1/x);$ and we are done.

Now try to answer where your error enters.

Used: Binomial expansion

An option:

$\dfrac{2x^2+x}{x-3}=$

$\dfrac{2((x-3)+3)^2+(x-3)+3}{x-3}=$

$2(x-3)+12+\dfrac{18} {x-3} +1+\dfrac{3}{x-3} =$

$2(x-3)+13+\dfrac{21}{x-3} =$

$2x+7+\dfrac{21}{x-3} .$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Other people have explained how you got the wrong answer, but another way that you can use your calculation as a step to a correct answer is to recognize that this method will give you the correct slope $ 2 $ but will not tell you the constant term.  So to find that, you take $$ \lim _ { x \to \infty } \Big ( \frac { 2 x ^ 2 + x } { x - 3 } - 2 x \Big ) \text , $$ and this will give you $ 7 $.  Therefore, the asymptote is $ 2 x + 7 $.